# Как вывести подкатегории у категорий произвольных типов записей WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Нашла только вот такой код:

```
    <?php
    if (is_category()) {
    if (count(get_categories('child_of='.$cat)))
    echo '<ul class="sub_categories">';
    $current_cat=get_query_var('cat');
    wp_list_categories('child_of='.$current_cat.'&title_li=&show_count=0'); 
    echo '</ul>';
    }
    ?>
```

Только он не работает. slug категорий произвольных типов записи doccat.